# GLES2 TouchEventPool was exhausted

Tags: java, android, touch, andengine

I am using onSceneTouchEvent to move player on TMX map:

```
 @Override
        public Scene onCreateScene() {
...
                mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
}

...

@Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

        switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {

        case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        mLastMotionX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                        mLastMotionY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

                        break;

        case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        mLastMotionX1 = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                        mLastMotionY1 = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

                        SpeedVector(mLastMotionX, mLastMotionY, mLastMotionX1,
                                        mLastMotionY1);                        
                        break;

        case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        mLastMotionX2 = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                        mLastMotionY2 = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
                        SpeedVectorStop(mLastMotionX, mLastMotionY, mLastMotionX2,
                                        mLastMotionY2);
                break;         
}

                return false;

        }

...

        public void SpeedVector(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {

                if ((Math.abs(x2 - x1) < 55) && (Math.abs(y2 - y1) < 55)) {


                        float r = (float) Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1))
                                        + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
                        float rx = (x2 - x1) / r;
                        float ry = (y2 - y1) / r;
                        new Vector2(rx * 100, ry * 100);
                        new Vector2(x2, y2);



                        if (speedThread) {
                                mPlayerBody.setLinearVelocity(rx * 15, ry * 15);
                        } else
                                mPlayerBody.setLinearVelocity(rx * 5, ry * 5);

                }
        }


public void SpeedVectorStop(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
                if ((Math.abs(x2 - x1) < 10) && (Math.abs(y2 - y1) < 10)) {
                        mPlayerBody.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
                }
        }
```

Also on the scene has a lot of other sprites (enemies) that pursue a player ( simple AI). Their position and speed changes depending on the distance to the player.
Accordingly, all data is updated in the next method:

```
@Override
                        public final void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
//some code
}
```

And when I touch on the scene a few times - AndEngine will crash
here is a LogCat:

> 05-05 17:13:06.539: V/AndEngine(2676):
>   org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was
>   exhausted, with 2 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more. 05-05
>   17:13:06.539: V/AndEngine(2676):
>   org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1
>   was exhausted, with 2 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more. 05-05
>   17:13:06.559: V/AndEngine(2676):
>   org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was
>   exhausted, with 3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more. 05-05
>   17:13:06.559: V/AndEngine(2676):
>   org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1
>   was exhausted, with 3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more. 05-05
>   17:13:06.579: V/AndEngine(2676):
>   org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was
>   exhausted, with 4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more. 05-05
>   17:13:06.579: V/AndEngine(2676):
>   org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1
>   was exhausted, with 4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>
> and etc.

Anyone encountered this issue?

The problem is very urgent and has no solution yet (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message is generated by the TouchEventPool contained as a private static member in the TouchEvent class.

This logs calls are generated by the line 136 in `GenericPool<T>` class, but this is not a problem, actually i receive them too in my application.

It is just to notify that the engine will allocate an additional touchEvent, since they are reused.

You can increase the starting pool by calling the right constructor in TouchEventPool, the `public GenericPool(final int pInitialSize)` constructor, or by exposing `public synchronized void batchAllocatePoolItems(final int pCount)`, always in TouchEventPool, and then calling it in your application with the right parameter.

By the way, unless you are storing the TouchEvent (you really shouldn't be!! If you need it, make a copy of it!), this is an info message that will not make your app crash.

Comment: But how I can call abstract constructor from class TouchEventPool ?

Comment: maybe:
private static int pInitialSize;

 private static final TouchEventPool TOUCHEVENT_POOL = new TouchEventPool(pInitialSize);

...
...
...

 public static final class TouchEventPool extends GenericPool<TouchEvent> {
    // ===========================================================
  // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
  // ===========================================================

  public TouchEventPool (final int pInitialSize)
  {
   super(pInitialSize);
  }
  @Override
  protected TouchEvent onAllocatePoolItem() {

   return new TouchEvent();
  }
 }

Comment: You can modify AndEngine TouchEvent file, add a constructor to TouchEventPool and call from it super(the number of events you want). But i must add that this is NOT the cause of your crash. This is a standard message of AndEngine. So don't stop looking for the bug ;)

Comment: Ok) 
I did not express myself well - the game is freeze and when I touch on scene this "items" continue to grow (

Comment: Well, this is expected. It did it this to me too, since andengine hang a bit when it allocates this objects. Using the solutions i pointed you in the previous messages will resolve your problem

Comment: Thx a lot) Tomorrow everything will be decided = )